# Compiler error in declaring template friend class within a template class

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, friend

I have been trying to implement my own linked list class for didactic purposes.

I specified the "List" class as friend inside the Iterator declaration, but it doesn't seem to compile.

These are the interfaces of the 3 classes I've used:

**Node.h:**

```
#define null (Node<T> *) 0

template <class T>
class Node {
 public:
    T content;
    Node<T>* next;
    Node<T>* prev;

    Node (const T& _content) :
        content(_content),
        next(null),
        prev(null)
    {}
};
```

**Iterator.h:**

```
#include "Node.h"

template <class T>
class Iterator {
 private:
    Node<T>* current;

    Iterator (Node<T> *);

 public:
    bool isDone () const;

    bool hasNext () const;
    bool hasPrevious () const;
    void stepForward ();
    void stepBackwards ();

    T& currentElement () const;

    friend class List<T>;
};
```

**List.h**

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Iterator.h"

template <class T>
class List {
 private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    unsigned int items;

 public:
    List ();

    List (const List<T>&);
    List& operator = (const List<T>&);

    ~List ();

    bool isEmpty () const {
        return items == 0;
    }
    unsigned int length () const {
        return items;
    } 
    void clear ();

    void add (const T&);
    T remove (const T&) throw (std::length_error&, std::invalid_argument&);

    Iterator<T> createStartIterator () const throw (std::length_error&);
    Iterator<T> createEndIterator () const throw (std::length_error&);
};
```

And this is the test program I've been trying to run:

**trial.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "List/List.cc"

int main ()
{
 List<int> myList;

 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  myList.add(i);
 }

 for (Iterator<int> it = myList.createStartIterator(); !it.isDone(); it.stepForward()) {
  cout << it.currentElement() << endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, the compiler gives me the following errors:

**Iterator.h:26: error: ‘List’ is not a template**

**Iterator.h: In instantiation of ‘Iterator’:**

**trial.cpp:18:   instantiated from here**

**Iterator.h:12: error: template argument required for ‘struct List’**

**List.cc: In member function ‘Iterator List::createStartIterator() const [with T = int]’:**

**trial.cpp:18:   instantiated from here**

**Iterator.h:14: error: ‘Iterator::Iterator(Node*) [with T = int]’ is private**

**List.cc:120: error: within this context**

Seems like it is not recognizing the friend declaration.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Don't define your own null (or NULL, or anything related) macro.  In the case of initializing data members, `0` works just fine.

Comment: I know it's ugly, it was only temporary. But I was quite sure C++ didn't allow implicit casting.

Comment: Casts are never implicit, but conversions are.  (Two sides of the same coin, you might say, and "conversion" is also used to name methods which convert a value among other uses, but that's a different type of conversion.)  What you need to initialize a pointer is another pointer of suitable type, or a null pointer constant; `0` is a perfectly fine null pointer constant (`NULL` is too, if you prefer).

Comment: You will also need to define your class template's (List's) methods in the header (instead of List.cc, which shouldn't be #included in good code), in the general case, because class templates and function templates aren't really classes and functions, they *generate* classes and functions, and the full code must be available to the compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try adding a forward declaration

```
template <class T> class List;
```

at the start of `Iterator.h` -- that might be what you need to allow the `friend` declaration inside the `Iterator` class to work.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is List has not been properly declared in Iterator.h.  Instead, nest the Iterator class inside List (automagically making it a template), which you'll likely want to do anyway (to use List::Iterator instead of renaming it to ListIterator or IteratorForList, as you would to have more than one Iterator in a namespace).

```
template<class T>
struct List {
  //...
  struct Node {/*...*/};
  struct Iterator {
    // ...
  private:
    Iterator(Node*);
    friend class List; // still required
  };
  //...
};
```